# R-Having trouble with aggregating data over dates

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to aggregate a table using `ddply()`.
My table looks like this:

```
Year  Month  Count
2000   Jan       1
2000   Jan       2
2001   Feb       2
2001   Feb       1
```

I want to sum up the counts based on year and month. So I would have 2000, Jan, 3 and 2001, Feb, 3.
My code is

```
ddply(df,???,sum(Count))
```

I am not sure how to add in multiple variables.

Comment: You could check the examples in `?ddply`.  Using your dataset,, `ddply(df, .(Year, Month), plyr::summarise, Count=sum(Count))`

Comment: By doing that I got the sum of all the counts (5) and The year and month did not aggregate.

Comment: I get `3` and `3` using `plyr_1.8.2`

Comment: I don't. I have the newest version of plyr installed and wrote in the exact same code.

Comment: No idea what is going on.  Try `aggregate(Count~., df, FUN=sum)` or `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Year, Month) %>% dplyr::summarise(Count=sum(Count))` or `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, list(Count=sum(Count)), .(Year, Month)]`

Comment: This could be a case of masking the function.  That is the reason I used `plyr::summarise`.  Not sure if you used the exact code as I showed or only `summarise`

Comment: I got the months and years to aggregate, however the sum is just giving me back 5 for 2000 Jan and 2001 Feb.

Comment: I am using an csv excel file. Could that be the reason why?

Comment: Could you update the post with the dput output of the first 4 lines. i.e. `dput(droplevels(yourdata[1:4,]))`

Answer (score 2):

We group by the variables 'Year', 'Month', and get the `sum` of 'Count' specifying `summarise` from the `plyr`.

Using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Year, Month), plyr::summarise, Count=sum(Count))
#  Year Month Count
#1 2000   Jan     3
#2 2001   Feb     3
```

Or we can use the formula method of `aggregate` from `base R`.

```
aggregate(Count~., df, FUN=sum)
 # Year Month Count
#1 2001   Feb     3
#2 2000   Jan     3
```

Or with `dplyr`, we group by the variables and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Year, Month) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(Count=sum(Count))
#   Year Month Count
#  (int) (chr) (int)
#1  2000   Jan     3
#2  2001   Feb     3
```

Or we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), group by the columns, and get the `sum` of 'Count'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Count=sum(Count)), .(Year, Month)]
#   Year Month Count
#1: 2000   Jan     3
#2: 2001   Feb     3
```

NOTE: When we load functions that are similar from other packages, it is better to use `packagename::function` (`plyr::summarise` and `dplyr::summarise`)

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L), 
Month = c("Jan", 
"Jan", "Feb", "Feb"), Count = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Month", "Count"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```